# How to use new version of Node Nan Persistent

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

With new version of `Nan` what would be the equivalent code for following:
The following code works with 0.12.* but not on 4.3.0 and later.

```
//1)  
//This is my object_
Persistent<Object> object_;

Local<Object> obj = Nan::New<Object>();
NanAssignPersistent(object_, obj); //Don't know what to replace with here


//2)
NanDisposePersistent(object_); //Don't know what to replace with here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nan` documentation shows how to deal with Persistents [here](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/persistent.md). It may also be useful to look at the [`nan` tests for Persistent](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/test/cpp/persistent.cpp).

Example:

```cpp
Local<Object> obj;
Local<Object> obj2;

// Create a persistent
Nan::Persistent<v8::Object> persistent(obj);

// Get a local handle to the persisted object
v8::Local<v8::Object> orig_obj = Nan::New(persistent);

// Change the persistent reference
persistent.Reset(obj2);

// Dispose of the persistent
persistent.Reset();
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and link. with string I am facing following issue: `static Persistent<String> oncomplete_sym;`  `oncomplete_sym.Reset(Nan::New("oncomplete").ToLocalChecked());` It says No matching member function to call Reset. It expects 2 parameters and only I am passing only one as mentioned in the document. For `Object`s i will try soon.

Comment: I am using `Nan` `2.2.0` version.

Comment: For string it worked for me after adding isolate as the first parameter. `oncomplete_sym.Reset(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), Nan::New("oncomplete").ToLocalChecked());`

Comment: If you have to deal with isolates explicitly that means you're not using the `Nan::` primitives/methods. Use `Nan::Persistent<..>` instead of `v8::Persistent<...>`.

Comment: Awesome, changed from Persistent from v8 to NaN and everything is working fine now (even for objects). thanks a lot :)